# Unable to connect to website when host machine is connected to Access Point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, wireless-access-point, iis-7.5

I am running Windows 10 and am hosting a website on my PC.  When connected to my router I can access the website no problem, but if I connect this computer to my Access Point, I can no longer access my website.

This leads me to believe the issue is from the computer being connected to the access point, right?

How can you host a web site from a computer that is connected to an access point?

And to ensure that Windows Firewall is not the culprit here, I have disabled windows firewall on the machine.

Edit ....
Router1 is my router connected to my cable modem and port forwarding is set-up on this router. Router2 is my AP and port forwarding is NOT set-up on this router. Port 80 in Router1 is set to forward to IP 192.168.12.153 (the IP of the desktop connected to the AP that hosts the website

Router2 has DHCP disabled and is on the same subnet as router1

Also, I just tested and typed `192.168.12.153` in my browser to see if it was just a host name that was incapable of resolving, but it seems my computer `192.168.12.098` can not see above IP.  Which seems as if the computers connected to router1 can not "see" computers connected to router2?

EDIT 2.....
The desktop hosting my website is connected to the AP via an ethernet cable, and has an IP assigned outside of my DHCP.  I have RDC set-up on the machine and my router is properly forwarding ports for RDC to work.  Which narrows it down to being an issue with IIS.  Does IIS require settings to be changed if it is connected to an access point and not directly connected to router1?

Comment: Have you configure Apache/IIS/etc to this?  Have you forwarded the port?

Comment: Does the AP need to have port forwarding set-up?  Do IIS settings change when connected to an AP?  Port forwarding is already set-up on the router.

Comment: @PinkSmellyBlueSocks, port forwarding is set up on the router to which IP address?

Comment: Router1 is my router connected to my cable modem and port forwarding is set-up on this router.  Router2 is my AP and port forwarding is NOT set-up on this router.  Port 80 in Router1 is set to forward to IP 192.168.12.153 (the IP of the desktop connected to the AP that hosts the website)

Comment: "the IP of the desktop": computers do not have IP addresses.  Network interfaces do.  It is still not clear from your question, but if your router is configured to port-forward to your computer's ethernet card, but the computer is connected only via wireless, not ethernet, then the port-forwarding is not likely to do anything.

Comment: The desktop hosting my website is connected to the AP via an ethernet cable, and has an IP assigned outside of my DHCP.  I have RDC set-up on the machine and my router is properly forwarding ports for RDC to work.  Which narrows it down to being an issue with IIS.  Does IIS require settings to be changed if it is connected to an access point and not directly connected to router1?